# Why I can't modify Timer.ineterval during runtime?

Tags: c#, timer

Here is the scenario I'm trying to achieve,
My program has a timer which its interval is set to 10 seconds (10000ms).
I want to check for a specific conditions, for example if a specific file exists or has changed, then change timer.interval accordingly.
Here's my code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Interval =10000;
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(WriteToConsole);
        timer.Start();
        if(fileExists(@"C:\temp\1.txt"))
        {
           timer.Interval =20000; //20 seconds
        }
        else if(fileExists(@"C:\temp\2.txt"))
        {
           timer.Interval =15000; // 15 seconds
        }

    }

   public static void WriteToConsole(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);

    }
```

But it doesn't work as I need it to.
I've already read these but couldn't find the solution.
[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx)-[2](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?649739-How-change-timer-interval-if-it-already-running)-[3](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/197034-c-net-changing-timer-interval-at-runtime/)

Comment: Did you try to `Stop` the timer before changing the interval and then `Start` it again. It would not be surprising that it would raise some exception if you changed the interval during the timer's execution

Comment: And what does not work, what is the behaviour of this code ?

Comment: It doesn't help that this clearly *isn't* your code, because `else if(@"C:\temp\2.txt")` wouldn't compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Sidewinder94 your suggestion did the job.  thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for inaccuracy in code, I missed somethings here and there during ctrl-C,ctrl-V from my code. thanks for mentioning. :)

Comment: You still haven't provided a [mcve] though. Aside from anything else, you haven't told us what the expected behaviour is vs the actual behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your start after you specify your interval, or else stop the timer and start again later.